# Jquery and id tags not working with fancybox properly

Tags: jquery, class, web

I've been studying the functionality of [this website](http://smallstudio.com.au/) and am curious if any one knows how the "fbrd" id tags are working with jquery? I've researched this for months and cant seem to duplicate. I'm new to jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have looked through the code and I have prepared an example for you.

You can find it [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/LvWXU/).

What they basically did was combining [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) events with the [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin.

The jQuery I used in the demo is:

```
$("#fbrd").hover(function() {
    $(".title").toggle();

});

$("#fbrd").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  }
  );


$("#fbrd").click(function() {

    $("#TheFancybox").html("<p id='display'>C:\>_Is this what you are looking for?</p><iframe width='560' height='315' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/lAl28d6tbko?autoplay=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");

    $(".fancyTrigger").fancybox();
    $(".fancyTrigger").trigger('click');
});
```

I didn't do EXACTLY what they did on the site but my demo should give you some intuition about how jQuery works and how to use the functions. You can start changing the settings to your liking. If you don't know why something works the way it does, ask for help in the comments.

Good luck.

### Update

To show how to make the FancyBox take another size then the size of the content it is displaying, you can set the parameters of the FancyBox like so:

```
$(".fancyTrigger").fancybox({
   'width':'90%',
   'height':'90%',
   'autoSize' : false,
   'fitToView':  false
});
```

A demo for this setup can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvWXU/5/).

A full screen demo can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvWXU/5/embedded/result/).

Good luck!

Comment: This works pretty good.  Thanks!  Their box opens up and automatically fills the screen.  Is that functionality within their CSS? If so, do you see which CSS file is creating that functionality?

Comment: I guess if I understood the "< li id="fbrd_01"" tag I could get farther.

Comment: The behaviour about filling the screen is determined by the parameters you pass to the fancybox. Please read [this](http://fancybox.net/howto) and [this](http://fancybox.net/api). Also, in my demo I changed the `li` tag to a `div` tag because it **doesn't matter**: you can change the CSS to your own liking. So please let go of the idea of *understanding the `li` tag* because it makes no sense. With the demo and the `FancyBox API` you have all the tools you need.

Comment: Also, if you think my submitted answer answers your question sufficiently: please consider accepting it. (Green button next to my answer)

Comment: I created a sandbox and everything you've posted works great.  Thanks for all your help.  Not so much on the actual site though.  I have created html content just like Small Studio is using, but instead of fancybox triggering, the html content opens up as it's own page.  You are absolutely correct in suggesting I study the API a little more to make this work. Thanks again for all of your help.  You've gotten me a lot further than I was a day ago.

Comment: @TimHill Glad to help you out!